# Как вывести элементы из списка несколько раз в Python?

Tags: python, list

Всем привет. Есть список:

```
['1_собака', '2_кошка', '3_попугай', '4_медведь']
```

Я хочу вывести в print что-то вроде:

```
'собака', 'кошка', 'попугай', 'медведь', 'собака', 'кошка', 'попугай', 'медведь', 'собака', 'кошка'
```

Делаю так:

```
listtest = ['1_собака', '2_кошка', '3_попугай', '4_медведь']

lgo = [listtest[i] for i in range(50)]

print(lgo)
```

И мне выдается ошибка: *IndexError: list index out of range*, что логично. Ведь количество элементов в списке доходит только до 3. Вопрос - как сделать, чтобы элементы начинали перебираться заново, если выходят за рамки нумерации?

Comment: для этого есть, например, деление по модулю. Или можно написать цикл и сбрасывать в нем счетчик на ноль, когда будет достигнуть максимум. Или можно сразу расширить список до нужно длины.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Способ 1:

```
lgo = []
for i in range (50):
    idx = 0
    lgo.append(listtest[idx])
    idx += 1
    if idx == len(listtest):
        idx = 0
```

Способ 2:

```
lgo = [listtest[i % len(listtest)] for i in range(50)]
```

Способ 3:

```
m = 50 // len(listtest) + 1
lgo = listtest * m
lgo = lgo[:50]
```

Answer (score 3):

4 способ - "бесконечное FIFO"

```
lst = ['собака', 'кошка', 'попугай', 'медведь']
for _ in range(50):
    print(e := lst.pop(0))
    lst.append(e)
```

```
собака
кошка
попугай
медведь
собака
кошка
попугай
...
```

Answer (score 3):

В одну строку:

```py
any(map(lambda _: any(map(print, listtest)), range(5)))
```

в 2 строки:

```py
for _ in range(5):
    any(map(print, listtest))
```

Можно воспользоваться `cycle`:

```py
from itertools import cycle

listtest = ['собака', 'кошка', 'попугай', 'медведь']
it = cycle(listtest)
for _ in range(50):
    print(next(it))
```

Comment: тут количество выводимых элементов всегда будет кратно длине списка, и в конце выводится False

Comment: @Эникейщик, да все верно(False не печатается). Я думаю это и нужно.

Answer (score 2):

с использованием модуля `itertools` это может выглядеть так:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

l =  ['собака', 'кошка', 'попугай', 'медведь']
list(islice(cycle(l),10))

>>> out
'''
['собака',
 'кошка',
 'попугай',
 'медведь',
 'собака',
 'кошка',
 'попугай',
 'медведь',
 'собака',
 'кошка']
```