# Как выбирать рандомно элемент из списка, без повторений?

Tags: python

Пример: `list = ["one", "two", "three"]`

Мы берем из этих 3 элементов рандомно элементы без повторения, когда элементы кончаются, то начинаем заново, опять обращаемся к списку list и опять берем рандомно элементы и так по кругу.

Comment: Так рандомно или последовательно - one, two, three?

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467739/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2-python

Comment: Если нужно рандомно, тогда перемешиваете с помощью random.shuffle, проходите до конца циклом, сбрасываете счетчик на ноль, опять перемешиваете.

Comment: счетчик и количество элементов должно совпадать, верно?

Comment: В общем, есть три разных задачи: 1 - просто проходить по списку последовательно, потом заново - это дубликат вопроса, указанного участником Алексей Р. 2 - получать случайные значения из списка без повторений, потом начинать с начала. Это то что я описал в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470312/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83#comment2631447_1470312). 3 - ...

Comment: 3 - просто получать рандомные значения из списка, не важно - с повторениями или нет. Тогда просто берете бесконечный цикл, и через random.choice достаете случайные элементы.

Comment: Уточните, что именно вам нужно, потому что если 1 вариант (сейчас сформулировано именно так), то уже есть несколько готовых решений [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1467739/1365), и вопрос можно просто закрыть как дубликат.

Comment: Как выбирать рандомно элемент из списка, без повторений?
Пример: list = ["one", "two", "three"]

Мы берем из этих 3 элементов рандомно элементы без повторения, когда элементы кончаются, то начинаем заново, опять обращаемся к списку list и опять берем рандомно элементы и так по кругу.

Comment: изменил в статье текст, переформулировал

Answer (score 2):

Примерно тоже самое, что уже описали в комментариях и в ответе, просто с отдельной функцией-генератором, из которой можно брать значения:

```
from random import shuffle

def gen(lst):
    while True:
        shuffle(lst)
        yield from lst

lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i, item in enumerate(gen(lst)):
    # ограничим тремя проходами по списку для примера
    if i >= len(lst)*3:
        break
    print(item)
```

Пример вывода:

```
one
three
two
three
one
two
two
three
one
```

В такой парадигме можно брать произвольное число элементов из генератора, не обязательно кратное длине списка.

P.S. Ещё один способ перебрать нужное число элементов, пусть это будет `5`:

```
lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
g = gen(lst)
for _ in range(5):
    item = next(g)
    print(item)
```

Или так:

```
lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
for item, _ in zip(gen(lst), range(5)):
    print(item)
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы не писать количество проход, а чтобы оно само когда подошло к концу, заново начинало с начала

Comment: @BOOM Так тут автоматом начинает с начала. Ограничение тут стоит только для того, чтобы печать не была бесконечной, его можно просто убрать.

Comment: вот прошла 1 итерация, и вывод
two
three
one
а мне надо, чтобы при 1 итерации было только 1 элемент, а не 3

Comment: Вы мой код смотрели, запускали? Если поставите break сразу после print будет выведен ровно один элемент

Comment: если break поставить после принта, тогда элементы могут повторяться один за другим, по типу one и потом опять one при след прогоне

Comment: мне нужно так, чтобы к примеру было 5 итераций, то вывод будет рандомным, но без повторов при первом проходе по списку и т.д. То есть выведет сначала two, потом при след проходе one и при след проходе three, но так как в списке 3 элемента, а мне надо 5 итераций, то заново проходит по списку, то есть выведет сначала one, потом при след проходе three

Comment: Так поставьте в условии `if i >= len(lst)*3:` справа любую цифру - и будет столько итераций, сколько вы там напишете. Тут у меня выбрано кратное 3 число итераций, но это вовсе не обязательно. `if i >= 5:` - будет 5 итераций.

Comment: Добавил ещё код для понятности

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for _ in range(10):
    random.shuffle(lst)
    for x in lst:
        print(x, end = ' ')
    print()
>>>
a c b 
b a c 
b c a 
b c a 
c b a 
c b a 
b a c 
c a b 
a b c 
c b a
```

Comment: Бесконечно повторять - вместо for сделать while True: